# inflate xml layout with fill parent params

Tags: android

I have an android app when I press Button another xml file will inflate as the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
    childview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menubuttons, main,false);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            main.addView(childview);
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TopService.class));
        }
    });

}
```

and the xml file for the child layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/aaaaa"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" >

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:src="@drawable/bookmark2" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need the child view fill the parent view when inflate but it dose not working

Comment: Do you want that the child view fills the remaining vertical space? If that is the case try adding `android:layout_weight="1"` to the child view. **EDIT:** Also set its height to `0dp`.

Comment: Its filling the parent in the same file but when inflate to another file there is empty space around the inflated xml file